JusPay EC Headless- fetch process payload Android Kotlin
I have done the initialization of the HyperServiceHolder as per the doc and I am also getting success for initialization in the hyperService callback. I want to fetch PaymentMethods, List of Saved Cards, Available Upi etc. I dont know how to do it, in doc its mentioned we will be getting this from SDK only but nothing is mentioned. I have tried using the process method and passing payload as per the sample payload in doc but I am not getting response in the callback.

Given that you've mentioned you have done initialization and you've received the callback for the same, you should ideally have received the call back for process calls as well if you follow the doc. Double check if you have done the required configurations in Juspay's backend for your account (via dashboard) and if it is still not sorted, reach out to support@juspay.in

Hi! thanks for you reply. I have another question. I need to show a custom UPI approval screen when the user will pay via custom UPI ID. Couldn't find anything in the doc. Some apps like Swiggy, zomato and Pocket FM have a custom UI. Currently JusPay's default approval waiting is showing there.
